# Using AncestryDNA to work out whether mother or father is parent of half sibling?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis

How do I work out from viewing my shared matches on AncestryDNA which one of my parents is the parent of my half sibling?

Comment: Look for "shared matches", and see who is in that list. Relatives of your mother? Relatives of your father?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a known relative on your mother's or father's side that has also done an AncestryDNA test. That relative will presumably match your father or mother. If they also match the half sibling then that indicates which one is their parent. It is not proof because there could be other reasons for the matches. For proof you would need to test your father and your mother.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Thank you for joining and starting to participate in our community.